# Evaluable string as part of if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want like this:

```
var b = 2
var a = 1

var str = " && b == 2"

if (a == 1|str|) { some code }
```

I want to place the "str" in the code, I tried this:

```
document.write("<script lang='javascript'>" + "if (a == 1" + str + ") { some code }" + "</script>")
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: You should explain more about what you're trying to do, because that sure looks like you've taken a wrong turn somewhere.

Comment: Use `eval()` if the value of `str` is guaranteed to come from *your* code.

Comment: Why do you want to eval script strings?

Comment: @techfoobar: If it was his code, he could easily switch to a better solution not using `eval`

Comment: I was about to suggest using just a ternary operator, but I stopped when I couldn't figure out the condition. What are you actually trying to achieve ?

Comment: Are you trying to shorten your code?

Comment: Btw: To compare values, use `==` or strict `===`. A single `=` is the assignment operator, which will lead to unexpected behaviour if used in if-statements

Comment: It feels like a kind of [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Bergi - I was thinking like he has some kind of condition engine that spits out some particular condition string (not user input) depending on some other condition. But yeah, whatever the requirement, looks like it can be done in a better way.

Comment: eval("while (a == 1" + str + ") {randomNum3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - 5)) + 5}")

Comment: I tried this but it only works onload!????????

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do can be done using - like mentioned in comments - `eval()`, like this:

```
var b = 2
var a = 1

var str = " && b == 2"

if (eval("a == 1" + str) { //some code }
```

However, eval is considered a bad practice. This is because it is very hard to know the exact contents of the string that is being fed to `eval()` and therefore it is unpredictable what the code will do.

A better solution might be using boolean variables:

```
var b = 2;
var a = 1;

var bCorrect = (b == 2); // parentheses are not required, but do make it clearer.

if(a ==1 && bCorrect) { // some code}
```

I hope this helps you create a good solution. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

```
if (eval("a == 1" + str))
```

but you can probably come up with a better way to do this.  Maybe instead of a string you should use a function that takes the value of `a`?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code. I think it it will works for your problem.

```
<script lang='javascript'>

 var b = 2;
var a = 1;
var str = " && b == 2"
if ("a == 1"  + str ) { 
alert("ok");  //do something
}
```